# error: could not find gradle wrapper within android sdk. might need to update your android sdk

Tags: cordova, gradle

[image]

[image]
build-tools is:
android-5.1

platform-tools updated

my platforms are 
android-5.1 
android-17

Comment: this should solve your problem: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo-ur-android-sdk/22056/2

Comment: for me is not showing the build-tools installed in Andorid sdk
but i have the build-tools folder inside the sdk folder

Comment: Solved my problem on Mac OSX by using that solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42772536/2030937

Comment: If you installed Android Studio and it's version is 2.3.1, see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/43383039/882410

Answer (score 69):

If you have Android Studio installed, try to copy the templates directory of Android Studio

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates
```

to your android sdk tools directory:

```
C:\Android\sdk\tools
```

This did the trick for me :)

Comment: Actually the issue appeared after updating sdk with AS. And with this fix it is disappeared. But now I getting `Error: spawn EACCES`.

Comment: @extempl I had the same problem, there's a file you need to chmod, see my answer below.

Comment: You can also use cordova-android 6.2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo/42797817#42797817

Comment: Where "C:\Android\sdk\tools" is your Android SDK path. In my case "D:\AndroidSDK\tools" for example

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 45):

I had a similar problem with Android Studio running on a Mac.

I fixed it with the following commands:

```
cp -r /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools
chmod a+x ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew
```

Comment: Thank you. 
After that I've also needed to update gradle to latest version (3.3 now) with AS, copy those gradle files to sdk location:
`sudo cp -r ./platforms/android/gradle/wrapper ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradle &  sudo cp ./platforms/android/gradlew ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper &  sudo cp ./platforms/android/gradlew.bat ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
` since on `prepare` cordova copies those files into project and set the build variable to 3.3 url according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/39278785/506954

Comment: It occurs to me that you probably don't need the `sudo`. If someone tries this without and it succeeds, please report back :)

Comment: this worked for me when i got this error on my mac. I ran without sudo and it worked

Comment: Thanks, `sudo` removed. If someone tries this now and it *doesn't* work, trying putting sudo before both lines.

Comment: You are the champion @robbie_c

Comment: My savior! Saved my day.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Been looking for a solution for 4 days and this worked! Awesome

Comment: incredible A++++

Answer (score 43):

Update `ANDROID_HOME` path 
from

```
C:/Users/CURRENT_USER/android-sdk/tools/
```

to

```
C:/Users/CURRENT_USER/android-sdk
```

This should solve the problem
When you build it appends tool automatically to your `ANDROID_HOME` therefore it searches for graddle inside tools/tools directory which is not present at all.

Comment: Or wherever android sdk is installed or unpackaged.

Comment: Worked like a charm for fixing the same error when emulating android in Cordova.

Comment: if your on windows, close and open the cmd prompt after changing the path variable for the changes to take effect in the cmd prompt

Answer (score 19):

I was having same error: could not find gradle wrapper within android sdk; When I was building ionic, but I solved it.
I just downloaded [Android SDK tools package](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip) and copied extracted file to C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and then issued: build ionic/cordova again.

it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Got the same error in mac after updating the SDK Build Tools:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.  

Looked here: /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

Here is the method how I solved it:

1. Copied templates folder 
   from `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib` to `<ANDROID_HOME>/tools`
2. `chmod -R 777 <ANDROID_HOME>`

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me. Pity I had to download the studio to get a hold of this stuff on a server. .5GB uncompressed

Comment: chmod =R 777 <ANDROID_HOME> is really excessive.
from @robbie_c's answer, all you need is:
    chmod a+x <ANDROID_HOME>/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew

Answer (score 5):

update android project to cordova-android 6.2.1

```
cordova platform update android@6.2.1
```

for more details check the following links
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html

Comment: This is the right answer if your situation is this: you built a Cordova app then upgraded the Android SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the path manually ? (C:/Users/Arsan/android-sdk/sdk/tools/...)

I had to update my ANDROID_HOME path for this to work (to android-sdk/tools, so removing "sdk" from the path).

Steven

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue...   (2016-09-26, installed current version of Android SDK today)

**ANALYSIS**

I checked the installation and found out that the gradle wrapper is placed at a wrong location:    ...\Android\SDK\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper\gradle\wrapper/[here_are_the_files]

Hence there is   gradle/wrapper/gradle/wrapper    in the end....

That folder conatins:

- gradle-wrapper.jar
- gradle-wrapper.properties

**SOLUTION**

Moving the content of that folder to the  ...gradle/wrapper/-folder (hence 2 folders UPWARDS) solved my problem.

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry can you explain better this part, *Moving the content of that folder to the ...gradle/wrapper/-folder (hence 2 folders UPWARDS)*, don't get it

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue: could not find gradle wrapper within android sdk when i build ionic, but i was solve.
I just download Android SDK tools package361 and copy extract file to C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk and build ionic/cordova again.
Download link
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me as of today. My situation was that I got my Android studio updated. The most popular thing to replace the tools folder with the latest one wouldn't work for me. Infact is not required in some cases.

`npm update -g cordova` did the trick for me.

Then I removed the platform and added it again.

`ionic platform remove android`

`ionic platform add android`

This works for me in Ionic. I am sure `cordova platform remove/add android` will do the same stuff. Not tested though.

Working again !

Comment: I feel your pain.  Every time I get an Android Studio upgrade it blows away the SDK tools breaking my cordova build.  VERY annoying.

Answer (score 0):

set ANDROID_HOME in system variable as follows

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk
```

And set path in user variale as follows

```
appropriate jdkpath ; C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

Comment: I installed Android Studio as directed... the folder C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk was not created.  AS moved the SDK to a different location so this answer may be obsolete

Answer (score 0):

If you reinstalled Android Studio, there may be an `sdk1` and also `sdk` folder in this path:

```
C:\Users\CURRENT_USER\AppData\Local\Android\
```

If you have two sdk folders you will have to delete one of them. Keep the one that contains the AVD Manager.exe and SDK Manager.exe.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some error occured during the Android Studio installation, and the `tools/templates` directory didn't exist. I fixed it by uninstalling and then reinstalling the Android SDK Tools, in the Android Studio Package Manager.

Answer (score 0):

for my case: i figured out that templates folder is no longer available in the new sdk tools folder so:

- i have downgraded my android sdk tools from 25.3.1 to 25.2.3 and this is the link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip.
- uninstalled the latest sdk tools and replace it with the downloaded one.

Comment: i think C:/Users/CURRENT_USER/android-sdk/tools

Comment: @Dareon sorry for my late reply, try to download it and replace the "tools" folder inside Android Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your Android SDK having gradle/wrapper folder and having required files in that or not.If not update the Android SDK and try once.Make sure that you need set SDK root path in ANDROID_HOME in Environment variable in windows machines.