# Missing Gradle in Android SDK (using cordova + ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

Yep, i searched about this but nothing, just things about the ANDROID_HOME path, but in my case i don't think this is the real problem. When i try to do `ionic build android` i get this error:

> Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within android sdk. Might need to update yo
>   ur Android SDK.
>   Looked here: C:\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

And found that in `C:\Android\sdk\tools` i dont have "templates" folder, just this:

[image: sdk tools folder]

I see gradle wrapper only in this path `C:\Android\sdk\temp\ToolPackage.old01\templates\gradle\wrapper`

Why i don't have Gradle in my sdk folder? i am missing something? in SDK manager i have this installed:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think problem is with cordova version. Try to update it and re add platform.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42668185/could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-your-andr

Answer (score 26):

Had exactly the same problem. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652686/cordova-gradle-wrapper-missing-in-android-sdk) points out the reason behind it, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo) actually shows what to do.

In short:

- in Android Studio uninstall Android SDK Tools
- Download tools_r25.2.3-yourOPsystem.zip from [Android Downloads](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). Basicly same thing, older version.
- insert downloaded extracted tools folder in Android/sdk/ folder
  (MAC: /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools
  Win: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools)
- In project folder run:

`$ cordova platforms remove android`

`$ cordova platforms add android`

Comment: This is totally different, the question is from 2015 and this problem is new. The questions you link are for the new problem and your fix too.

Comment: You are indeed correct about it. So anyone who is looking for a fix for 2015 problem, should keep looking, others may find relief here.

Comment: for those who don't have android studio but just the sdk manager tool, type in "sdkmanager tools" what you need will be installed

Answer (score 8):

On Linux android studio version-162.3871768-linux
copy paste

```
\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\
```

to `Sdk/tools/`

Comment: you're a life saver

Answer (score 5):

You need to update **ANDROID_HOME** variable to point the **android-sdk** folder 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32507036/344895

Comment: No problem. The solution I reference in the answer helped me when I faced with the same issue

Answer (score 2):

you have to upgrade your cordova library

```
cordova platform update android@6.2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested upgrade cordova to version 6.5 and extract tools SDK. Nothing helps.
In my case I have Android Studio installation.

SOLUTION: Please find file `gradle-wrapper.jar` in your Android Studio installation (in may case `..\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper\gradle\wrapper\` ). Then copy whole directory templates to SDK location in subfolder tools.

Answer (score 0):

Set ANDROID_HOME to the SDK Path displayed in your Android SDK Manager.  The default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk if you didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html 
cheak Download Option and download tools only 
extact file and copy the templates folder
and paste in C:\Users(yourunername)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

Answer (score 0):

update your sdk tools download tools_r25.2.3-yourOPsystem.zip.
[direct download link][1]

/Users/username/Library/android/sdk/tools

Comment: please use this link..  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDjNCf_73TAhVI64MKHbhuDyUQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.google.com%2Fandroid%2Frepository%2Ftools_r25.2.3-windows.zip%3Fhl%3Did&usg=AFQjCNFpLJ8y-MbcXbY9gatR-oyFyVN3wQ&sig2=qlsSQ-3SHMGgR1PqGWWK-g

Answer (score 0):

You cant find gradle in latest sdk. So try to install it manually. Follow this link

https://gradle.org/install