# Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK - Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I know there are lots of questions similiar to this one, but i couldn't find a solution for my problem in any of those. Besides, I'll provide details for my specific case.

I coded an Ionic project in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and now I have to build it for release. So I run the command:

```
cordova build --release android
```

And I'm shown the following error:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

- I don't have this `templates/gradle/wrapper` directory.
- My Android Studio is 2.3, the latest version for now
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 25.0.3
- Android SDK Tools 25.3.1
- All Android versions from 2.1 (Eclair) to 7.1.1 (Nougat)

After extensive research, I put all the Android Studio-related environment variables in the file `/etc/environment`. So now it looks like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"

ANDROID_HOME=/home/<user>/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_HOME

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export JAVA_HOME

GRADLE_HOME=/opt/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2
export GRADLE_HOME
```

Now, for the sake of testing the environment variables, I run the following commands:

```
source /etc/environment
echo $PATH
echo $ANDROID_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $GRADLE_HOME
```

And all the path variables are correctly displayed.

**So, it looks like the environment variables are like they should be according to the various similar questions and in tutorials i've searched. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Why do I still get the Gradle Wrapper error?**

Answer (score 247, accepted):

I just experienced the same problem.

It may be an occlusion in the instructions regarding how to install (or upgrade) Android Studio with all the SDK Tools which both you and I missed or possibly a bug created by a new release of Studio which does not follow the same file conventions as the older versions. I lean towards the latter since many of [the SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123898/missing-gradle-in-android-sdk-using-cordova-ionic#39469596) on this topic seems to point to an ANDROID_PATH with a folder called android-sdk which does not appear in the latest (2.3.0.8) version.

There appears to be [a workaround though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177145/4941585), which I just got to work on my machine. Here's what I did:

- Download tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip from [Android Downloads](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip?hl=id).
- Extracted zip on desktop
- Replaced C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools with extracted
  sub-folder tools/
- In project folder:

  $ cordova platforms remove android
  $ cordova platforms add android

You may also need to force remove the node_modules in android.
Hopefully this helps.

Comment: THX, I've been trapped in the same phenomenon, now recovered my environment by your remedy. I think it is the fault of Google, so cordova developers shall wait for the next, corrected update.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue. Downgraded "Android SDK Tools" 25.2.3 which fixed the issue. We should probably wait for update from Google/Android team.

Comment: THANKS! Your answer worked perfectly. We'll have to wait for an update on this bug. You saved my work :D

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem, found similar workaround here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk/79527/6

Comment: Replacing only the tools folder did the trick for me. Did not have to remove and add the platform.

Comment: I did the same thing and worked. But when I updated tools from Android SDK manager, the same problem resurfaced - 'ANDROID_HOME' missing and after setting that I got error message - 'gradle file missing' while building the App via PhoneGap CLI.

Comment: Very useful, for Mac you can do the same except for downloading tools for Windows, you download from Mac on this address: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip

Comment: The original file can be accessed directly here: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip?hl=id

Comment: Tools for linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip

Comment: I am still get similar after manually downloading sdk tools .please any one me.getting  Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio"Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5,Cordova Platforms : android 6.2.3 ,Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2.please any one help me i open new question.here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45770757/error-while-building-android-project-in-ionic-v1)

Comment: downloaded https://afterroot.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/android-sdk-tools-direct-links/ and replaced from <ANDROID_HOME>/tools to 25.2.5                   and tried to install plugin again and worked fine

Comment: For me, removing and then adding the android plugin did the trick (didn't have to do anything else).

Comment: Thank you so much it's worked for me while replacing tools_r25.2.3.

Comment: tnx, i was searching all day

Answer (score 258):

Edit 3:

Cordova Android 6.2.2 has been released and it's fully compatible with SDK tools 26.0.x and 25.3.1. Use this version:

`cordova platform update android@6.2.2`

or

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```

Edit 2:

There has been another Android SDK tools release (26.0.x) that is not fully compatible with cordova-android 6.2.1.

Edit:
Cordova Android 6.2.1 has been released and it's now compatible with latest Android SDK.

You can update your current incompatible android platform with
`cordova platform update android@6.2.1`

Or you can remove the existing platform and add the new one (will delete any manual change you did inside `yourProject/platforms/android/` folder)

`cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.2.1`

You have to specify the version because current CLI installs 6.1.x by default.

Old answer:

Sadly Android SDK tools 25.3.1 broke cordova-android 6.1.x

For those who don't want to downgrade the SDK tools, you can install cordova-android from github url as most of the problems are already fixed on master branch.

`cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android`

Comment: Will be correct answer once cordova-android 6.2.0 is released, at the moment is in development and not everybody is willing to use it before it's released.

Comment: Where can I keep track of this issue and cordova-android releases?

Comment: I also got the following error when running `cordova run android --list`. Is this related? `An unexpected error has occured while running list-emulator-images with code 2: Error: /Users/Shawn/Desktop/FRCCApp/platforms/android/cor
dova/lib/list-emulator-images: Command failed with exit code 2`

Comment: Yes, that error is also related. Most of the problems are linked in this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12554. Once it's released, it will be announced on the blog https://cordova.apache.org/blog/ and on twitter.

Comment: The release is now up on the npm repositories, although it doesn't seem to be being used automatically yet.  `cordova platform add android@6.2.0` works, though.

Comment: Yeah, it requires a CLI release to be used as default, that will take longer

Comment: Removing platform and adding it again just worked for me.

Comment: I'm using Android Tools 26.0.2 with android@6.2.3 but I still have the issue Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

Comment: @MichaelBurger that's a different issue, you now need Gradle installed in your system and set it in your path.

Comment: Using `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android` solved it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @chrjs `cordova platform add android@6.2.3` is safe to use now, you don't need to add github version and it might be unstable, better use 6.2.3 as is the latest released one

Comment: I'm on Cordova 7.0.1 and I'm getting the error: `Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.` Any advice?

Comment: @EthanKeller but did you had the android platform added previously? If that's the case, remove it `cordova platform rm android` re add it
`cordova platform add android`

Comment: Removed, added 6.2.2, got error `cordovaProject.projectConfig.getFileResources is not a function`

Comment: You also need Cordova CLI 7.0.1

Comment: just removing and adding the platform or updating the android platfrom fixes this issue. Confirmed after 4 hours of frustration. Thanks.

Comment: What must we write in config.xml in case using 7.0.1 ? Which SDK Version?

Comment: @nottinhill I don't understand the question, I didn't mention anything about the config.xml on my answer

Comment: Why not just `android@latest`?

Comment: @Seanny123 by the time I answered, it wasn't even released, I've been editing with the version numbers that were fixing issues related to the Google changes. Now you can use `android@latest` without problems.

Comment: I m using latest version of cordova, android@6.2.3 is default. The error still exists

Comment: @sziraqui did you remove and re add the platform?

Comment: yes, tried **each and very solution mentioned on this post**,  finally i had to install gradle from ubuntu repo

Comment: @sziraqui, ah, yeah, since cordova-android 6.2.1 it requires Android Studio or Gradle to be installed on the user's system to work

Comment: I have Android Studio installed and working, I work on native android, I m trying cordova. Why can't cordova detect gradle that comes with Android Studio?

Comment: It's supposed to detect it, it works in macOS, probably nobody tested it on ubuntu, can you report it on issues.cordova.io?

Comment: ionic cordova platform add android@latest fixed my prob . Thanks for ans

Comment: @LAnantaPrasad latest is 7.1.1, that should also work and it's newer, or at least 6.4.0 that is latest 6.x.x

Comment: Great fix! Recently upgrade to latest android studio and just needed to update cordova android to the above. Way to go!

Comment: well, you could give cordova-android 8.0.0 a go as it's latest one

Comment: Got me past there - now I get `Could not determine java version from '13.0.2'.`

Comment: Cordova only supports java 8 at the moment

Answer (score 57):

(Basically what @user3464070 already said)

For Mac:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk
# download latest tools
curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
# overwrite existing tools folder without prompting
unzip -o tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
# clean up
rm tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip
```

Comment: First line could be `cd $ANDROID_HOME` for simplicity?

Comment: @toxaq could be but `$ANDROID_HOME` is not defined on my machine.

Comment: thx a lot. your commands + using android@6.1.2 work like a charm on mac!

Comment: Perfect answer! Seems like the easiest solution! Thanks :)

Answer (score 45):

1. If you have android studio installed within your system, then copy the templates folder from `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates`
2. Paste it in the folder `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools`
3. Run the command: `ionic build android`

All necessary jar files will be downloaded and apk file for the application will be generated.

**Note:** Set environment variables to 
 `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools`.
 Also set user-name to your current username.

Comment: Simple and easy solution!

Comment: This is an easy and economical solution for those who have Android Studio.

Comment: it actually worked for me.. when other solutions didn't. Too bad it seems mostly to depend on cordova/ionic/sdk/android studio versions

Comment: As of 2018 and working with 2 different versions of Cordova, I can vouch for this solution as one that works and does not need additional downloads.

Answer (score 25):

For Linux there is even a bit better solution.

Navigate to
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

and download the command line tools zip file (bottom of the page) for linux. Extract them to your ..../Android/Sdk/ folder so you overrwrite/extend your tools folder. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Yeah, R J answered the Windows workaround for the problem, and your answer is the Linux solution. Useful for someone who doesn't know how to solve Windows' `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` to Ubuntu's `/home/user/Android/Sdk`

Comment: @rbenvenuto The answers are basically the same. Download tools, extract the zip folder and save the extracted content to your idk's tools folder. How difficult can it be to understand? I'm using a Mac and will save to ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools Need I steal someone's up votes for explaining the same thing in different words?

Comment: @Anon Yep, can't deny his answer was pretty much the same explanation with different words. But i can see some value in it for struggling beginners like me lol

Comment: previous versions are not available anymore in developer.android.com

Answer (score 20):

For anyone who is still having this issue, this worked for me:

```
    cordova platform update android@latest
```

then build and it will automatically download the newest gradle version and should work

Comment: +1 This works as @ August 2017 and updates you to `cordova-android@6.2.3`.  Older answers may or may not work or be correct any more.  This situation keeps changing and is directly caused by Android SDK 25.3.1 dropping support for the android binary, as described here: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/05/android-release.html

Comment: Still working as at Mar 2018. I don't create new cordova projects often, this is the first since my previous comment.  It had the same `could not find gradle wrapper` error.  I had to look up the solution on SO again. This is a per project fix, must be applied to every new cordova  project you create. Would upvote twice if I could, this is the 2nd time this answer has saved me now.

Answer (score 12):

There's no need to downgrade Android Tools.
On Windows, Gradle moved from:

```
C:\Users\you_username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
```

to:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

So you just need to adjust your path so that it points to the right folder.

Comment: I did the opposite, moving the wrapper to my AppData and it works fine ! Thanks ^_^

Comment: [A new version of Cordova has been published recenly (five days ago) to solve this problem](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/04/28/android-release.html)

Comment: Copy the content of the wrapper folder from this path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle\wrapper to C:/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

Answer (score 8):

if you have this error when you `ionic run android --device`

```
## codova - android update 
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform update android
```

Answer (score 6):

Just copied everything from typical Android Studio installation.
From:
D:\sw\dev\android\studio\plugins\android\lib\templates

(the whole templates directory)

To:

D:\sw\dev\android\sdk\tools

Tested with
ionic build android

Comment: This was the solution in my case. After this solution, you might get the license message. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383323/cant-accept-license-agreement-android-sdk-platform-24/40383457#40383457

Answer (score 6):

This problem occurs when you dont have the gradle wrapper into your SDK tools.

Like the previous responses said, you can update to last `cordova-android` version (it works), but if you want to keep working with `cordova-cli@6.4.0` and `cordova-android@6.0.0`, just copy the folder from android studio ex.;

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/
cp -r templates/ $ANDROID_HOME/tools/templates
chmod +x $ANDROID_HOME/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew
```

In my case, I am using the `cordova-plugin-fcm` and it was tested with old version of cordova-android, so I can not use `cordova-android@2.x` (not yet).

Answer (score 4):

For Linux just make a symlink, like this:

```
ln -s /android/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates /android/sdk/tools/templates
```

Comment: Didn't test the symlink solution, but on my system `/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/templates/gradle/wrapper/gradlew` has no execute permission. Make sure to chmod it before trying.

Comment: I don't have template/ folder under `sdk/tools`.

Answer (score 4):

On linux (Ubuntu in my case) just install gradle:

`sudo apt-get install gradle`

Edit: It seems as though ubuntu repo only has gradle 2.10, for newer versions: https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: None of the above solutions worked for me. I am using latest ver of cordova 7.0.1. Installing gradle from ubuntu repo solved the issue. Its 2017 and still cordova doesn't know to use Android studio's  builtin gradle

Answer (score 3):

**This solved my problem.**

I just downloaded 
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip214 and overwrite the tools folder at ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools

Answer (score 2):

Just recently, I also encountered similar problem, and after I did this, it works:

I edited the file in `/etc/profile`

```
sudo nano /etc/profile

export JAVA_HOME=/home/abdul/java/jdk1.8.0_131
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export ANDROID_HOME=/home/abdul/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME=/home/abdul/android-studio/gradle
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME/gradle-3.2/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_ANDROID_HOME/m2repository
```

Other info (just in case):

Not quite sure about `m2repository` part, in the first try it pass the grandle but there is another error (gradlew-command-failed-with-exit-code-

1. I check if in android studio the repository is active, and it's not active, I try to activate it, and when I try it again (Cordova build Android), it download a few other file, maybe from the repository? And then when I delete the path, it still works.
   (also thanks to Marcin Orlowski sample so then I can understand about export path better).

I use:

- Linux Mint Serena
- node : v6.10.3
- npm : 3.10.10
- Cordova : 7.0.0
- Android Studio : 2.3.1
- Android SDK platform-tools : 25.0.5
- Android SDK tools : 26.0.2

Hope it can help anyone who might have the same problem like mine and need this too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No need to update sdk. Try to install it manually.
Follow instructions in this link

https://gradle.org/install

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked for me as of today. My situation was that I got my Android studio updated. The most popular thing to replace the tools folder with the latest one wouldn't work for me. Infact is not required in some cases.

`npm update -g cordova` did the trick for me.

Then I removed the platform and added it again.

`ionic platform remove android`

`ionic platform add android`

This works for me in Ionic. I am sure`cordova platform remove/add android` will do the same stuff. Not tested though.

Working again !

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything here twice in different order, I reinstalled everything and before doing `cordova platform add android` I went to `templates/gradle` and ran `gradlew.bat`.  After this completed, I was able to add the android platform without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.2
```

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
cordova platform update android@6.1.2
```

And make sure that Android Studio and Android Studio environment variable refrence to same location.

I fix this by copying Android Studio from:

```
D:\Program Files\Android
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Android
```

Answer (score -1):

After cordova upgrade to 7.0.x, the gradle path has been changed as discussed above. To get it working before official fix comes out, just manually install the gradle and set it in your Environment.

1. Go https://gradle.org/install download the Binary packages
2. Unzip it,remember the path, eg., My one at: E:\Gradle
3. Set the environment variables, like on Windows add E:\Gradle\bin

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

After experienced the same issue, just rename the package name in config.xml, attribute id with a name without "-" inside...

i.e.

com.web-projet.appname

renamed into :

com.webprojet.appname

and all was correct...

If it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Installing cordova version 5.0  helps me:

```
npm install -g cordova@5.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and for me, it worked by just using two commands:-

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Easy and simple solution for MAC

**My Issue was**

```
cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jerilkuruvila/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /Users/jerilkuruvila/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

**Solution**

```
jerilkuruvila@Jerils-ENIAC tools $ cd templates
-bash: cd: mkdir: No such file or directory
jerilkuruvila@Jerils-ENIAC tools $ mkdir templates
jerilkuruvila@Jerils-ENIAC tools $ cp -rf gradle templates/
jerilkuruvila@Jerils-ENIAC tools $ chmod a+x templates/
```

cordova build android again working now !!!

Comment: Do you explain this? Why happen?