# Ionic build error: occurred configuring root project 'android'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration

Tags: android, ionic2, android-support-library

When i run ionic run android i am facing the errors.

The errors are snipped below

[image]

Comment: Obviously, you have problems with your dependencies.

Comment: Now i am facing this Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo

Comment: @suraj tanq u for helping me :)

Comment: no problem... :)

Answer (score -1):

hi solve the problem installing `Gradle` in my computer from the oficial website.
Add the /bin folder to the Environment variable PATH, check it typing `gradle -v` at your bash.
Then create a folder oin your skd/tools call it `/templates/gradle/wrapper` then execute inside `/wrapper` the system bash and type `gradle wrapper`. When the process finish, all wheel ok!