# PHONEGAP - Error while starting emulated android on phonegap; I use the SDK installed by android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, emulation

The error I get on the console; When I run the command "phonegap emulate android"

->Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK. Looked here: C:\Users\wende\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced this issue (among many others) in my attempts to get a phonegap app to work in my environment.

I found a solution in the second response (by jcesarmobile) to this question:
[Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo)

Specifically, I had to make sure my Android Studio and Android SDK Tools were updated to the latest version, and then I had to update my Cordova Android platform to version 6.2.2.

```
phonegap cordova platform rm android
phonegap cordova platform add android@6.2.2
```