# Linux 16.04 : Cannot cordova build (versios 6.2.2

Tags: cordova, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying so hard to run cordova... But i got the same exact error such as :
" Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio "

Or my Path on the baschr is correct. I update Android Studio SDK with the right path on it.

But i still get this error.

I'vre read a lot of comments about it and try almost everything such as copy/paste tools android sdk (downloaded on the android site ) into my path folder with no success at all.

What shall i do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

In fact, i just installed manually the gradle with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

And it seems to work !

Comment: Nice. +1 for posting your accurate answer.!

Answer (score 0):

Gradle files are present in Android SDK. Your Android SDK is missing (atleast the path could not be found). Do install Android SDK and place the path in `PATH` in System Environment Variables.

Reference here - [Android Builds Now Using Gradle By Default](https://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/).

If you have Android SDK installed already, Check [How To Read and Set Environmental Variables on a Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-linux) for more details.

Check this [Configuring Gradle](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#configuring-gradle) documentation.

If you dont have Android SDK, then refering to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639125/5213405),

- Visit the [Downloads Page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) of Android and SDK Tools
- Download Android command line tools given at the **bottom** of the page. You need **not** install Android Studio.
- Then set environment variables accordingly.
- Then In project folder:

  ```
   $cordova platforms remove android
   $cordova platforms add android
  ```

Comment: Great ! Thank you for your answer. I already installed SDK so i will follow the second link. I'm going to tell as soon as possible if it finally works !