# Ionic - Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build my ionic app with android sdk:

```
ionic build android
```

The following error is displayed:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /home/ehipolito/Android/Sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

I found some suggestions to solve but doesnt worked to me.

```
Android studio Version 2.3.3
ionic -v
2.2.1
cordova -v
6.5.0
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/ehipolito/Android/Sdk
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution that works, in the folowing post: 
[Cordova update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446759/1540676)
I tried the othes but just that works to me