# Ionic Android build Error: No installed build tools found - I tried all the suggestions I found in similar questions asked by others here

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework

I use Windows 7. When I run ionic cordova build android command in root of ionic project, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: myAPP/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 64

What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

**My environment variables:**

ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android

GRADLE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2

JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
JDK_HOME= C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

PATH= C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\builder;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\sdk-common;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\lib

**Installed build tools** (in this folder: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\builder):

2.3.0

2.3.1

2.3.2

2.3.3

In C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\sdk-common folder:

25.3.0

25.3.1

25.3.2

25.3.3

**I tried everything from here:**

[ionic build Android | error: No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190355/ionic-build-android-error-no-installed-build-tools-found-please-install-the)

[Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo/42639125#42639125)

It still doesn't work, I get the same error message. I downloaded the tools from here: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip. 
Then I copied the folders and files in the Android Studio's tools folder. It was suggested that I replace them on the second link above. However, I didn't want to replace those files because the folder and file names are different: 
[The downloaded tools folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z5Qv.png)

[The tools folder of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDqQh.png)

Comment: what is your `cordova-android` version?

Comment: in your project, platforms->platforms.json, what is android version?

Comment: Cordova version: 7.1.0

Comment: platforms.json:     {
  "windows": "5.0.0",
  "android": "6.3.0"
}

Comment: Sorry for late response.. but I think you need to open up your SDK manager and install later versions of build tools