# Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK. Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build android project based on Cordova but I have error as follows:

> Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to
>   update your Android SDK.

I am using `cordova 6.4.0`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: just execute the command the following commands. npm install -g cordova; cordova platform rm android; cordova platform add android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is an issue where who are using Cordova older versions(eg. `Cordova 6.4.0`), From android `SDK Tools`, `Revision 25.2.3` (`November 2016`) onwards they have removed templates folder from the tools which are required to create build till `cordova-android@6.2.2.`

Use following steps it will help you,

1. Download the **tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip** from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html)
2. Extract the zip
3. Go to Android SDK path then go to in your tools folder
   Replaced `..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` with extracted sub-folder of `tools/`  (`templates` folder)
4. And now do the build process again, your issue will be resolved.

   `$ cordova build android / cordova run android`

Also please check the similar type of question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613882/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo).

Hopes this will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

just execute the following commands.

***npm install -g cordova; 
cordova platform rm android; 
cordova platform add android;***

It will update you cordova to latest version and remove and add the platform newly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for above question**

Those who are using cordova older versions(eg. `cordova 6.4.0`), i.e. **Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK.** Might need to update your Android SDK so solution for this is as follows

Download the `tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip` from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html link
Extract it and copy the templates folder from it
Go to android sdk path then go in tools folder
Paste the templates folder here
And now do the build process again, your issue will be resolved.
Why this issue From SDK Tools, Revision `25.2.3 (November 2016)` onwards they have removed templates folder from the tools which is required to create build till `cordova-android@6.2.2.`