# Cordova/Phonegap Android target: not installed [Android Studio Installed]

Tags: android, macos, cordova, phonegap-build, android-studio-2.3

Still facing this issue. I searched all over google could not found a  solutions.

- Mac OSX Sierra
- Android Studio 2.3
- Cordova/ Phonegap (Latest Version)

Requirements check results for android:

1. Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
2. Android SDK: installed true
3. Android target: not installed Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
4. Gradle: installed

> Error: Some of the requirements check failed

```
.bash_profile
================================
# Setting JAVA_HOME Path

JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home"

# Setting ANDROID_HOME Path

ANDROID_HOME=“/Users/{localpath}/Library/Android/sdk”

# Setting GRADLE_HOME Path

GRADLE_HOME=“/Users/{localpath}/Library/Android/gradle/gradle-3.4”

export PATH=“${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}”
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:$PATH"
export PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

Andriod Manifest

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.company.myAPP" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```

[Android Studio Installed SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOoNZ.png)

Comment: this answer actually helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42639125/717251

Answer (score 16):

Facing exactly the same error, I encountered [this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo-ur-android-sdk/22056/9#post_10) on forum.ionicframework.com:

> As easy as that.
>
> I had the problem on Mac, so I did download the [SDK tools373](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-macosx.zip), copy-paste it in /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk, and it worked instantly.
>
> But I absolutly don't know what causes the issue.

And I don't know what causes the issue either, but it helped me and everything works as expected.

Comment: This is a magical, wonderful answer and should be the accepted one. Wonder why that is / didn't come with Android Studio.

Comment: Same here... A lot of files were missing when installed via the Android Studio compared to the package which i downloaded from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools - Thanks!

Comment: FYI: I had to add `export PATH="/Users/*USERNAME*/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH"` into my `~/.bash_profile` followed by reloading it with `source ~./.bash_profile` for this to work for me. Just be sure to replace *USERNAME* with your username!

Answer (score 2):

Facing with same error.
Maybe this info will be helpful.

In the latest Android SDK Tools (v25.3.1), the `android` command no longer operates as expected and instead exits with a non-zero status code and provides a message telling folks to use the `sdkmanager` and `avdmanager` commands.

try to execute `android` in terminal if it will return something like this:

`The android command is no longer available.For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager`

then you need to downgrade your SDK to v25.2.5 or less. Instruction can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version)

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded Android SDK
FROM 
**latest release 10.0(q) to API level 29** 
TO 
**9.0(pie) API level 28**
by the user guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version) 
then added this in a .bash_profile

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

everything works fine 
I hope that it can help someone