# Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

"Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."

Facing this issue while building the Cordova Project through Terminal, if I run through Android Studio I am not getting the issue what will be the root cause for this issue.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667277/cordova-phonegap-android-target-not-installed-android-studio-installed

Answer (score 21):

This is just a workaround while cordova is being updated:

1. Remove directory /Android/sdk/tools
2. download https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip
3. Unzip
4. Place new folder in /Android/sdk/tools

Answer (score 1):

If nothing was worked, try

```
cordova platform remove android
```

and

```
cordova platform add android
```

in your Cordova project

**edit**

*Solution 2*

Remove cordova

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
```

Add cordova

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Remove Android platform from project

```
cordova platform remove android
```

Add Android platform again

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Android home variable through command line.
Try these commands to set Android_Home variable.

> export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Android/Sdk
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

PS: Replace ~/Android/Android/Sdk with your Android SDK path.

Comment: Issue got fixed. Thank you

Comment: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK. Getting this error again

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.give the path to the android sdk installed.

Comment: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK. Getting this error