# How to run an ionic v1 app on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just received an ionic v1 app that I have to make some changes,but after a fresh installation of ionic, I'm unable to run it. Every time that I run `ionic run android` in the ionic CLI, I receive this error:

> WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please
>   rename it.  Using this version of Cordova with older version of
>   cordova-android is deprecated. Upgrade to cordova-android@5.0.0 or
>   newer.
>
> Error: Your android platform does not have Api.js

For the moment I can not migrate to Ionic 2.

What can I do to run/build it?

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, when you install Ionic this way

> npm install -g cordova ionic

You are getting the last CLI that works with [Ionic 2](http://ionic.io/2), [Angular 2](http://learnangular2.com/) and a [different project structure](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/migration/#project-structure). If you want to run and build an Ionic v1 project you need the tools that works with your version.

To install a specific version you need to add @ symbol  after the name package and the version that you want for example:

> npm install -g ionic@1.7.14
>
> npm install -g cordova@6.0.0

Also you have to keep in mind that Android has been improving their tools too, and this version of cordova doesn't work properly with the latest Android tools chain. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950169/android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at-the-defau) can help you to download and setup the android tools for this version of cordova.

After that you will be able to run `ionic run android`