# Android target: not installed (cordova requirements)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am pretty new to ionic and I tried to build my app, but it failed, so I runned “cordova requirements” and I got this error:

```html
$ cordova requirements
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also I have installed APIs form sdk tools, and added tools to path in system variables.

Comment: What's the target version you would want to run your app on?

Comment: Api for Android 4.0.1

Comment: up to Android 6.0.0

Comment: ok, then you would need the target platform up to 23 and I would suggest a minimum of target platform of 19

Comment: Thanks, but I have already installed it, here is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cORh.png Do I need something else?

Comment: It still doesnt work btw

Comment: This worked for me just a few minutes ago. Looks like the latest tools in the Library/Android/sdk/tools folder don't work properly. ( i'm on os/x ) I renamed the folder dumped the new tools from the link in and worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875742/9674980

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it simply! As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097394/2642351 try installing JDK version less than 9, like JDK 8 or so. And update your JAVA_HOME path in the Environment Variables

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall existing JDK which has version above 9.

Install this jdk (cordova works in jdk 8+) :
https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/jdk-8u191-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use android sdk manager to download targets other then bundled by default. But before that check the android target version in your Ionic app.

You can launch the SDK Manager in one of the following ways:

> From the Android Studio File menu: File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
>
> From the Android Studio
> Tools menu: Tools > Android > SDK Manager. From the SDK Manager icon
> (enter image description here) in the menu bar.

add the min and target version in config.xml

```
<platform name="android">

  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="XX"/> 
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="XX"/>

  <!--other line code -->

</platform>
```

Comment: How to check or add android target to ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

For me below steps saved me

1. Install the Android Studio 5.0 to 7.1 from menu: File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
2. Install JDK 8 +
3. Set JAVA_HOME in system variables
4. Restart machine