# Cordova wont bulid for android

Tags: android, windows, cordova, android-sdk-tools

Why the build is not working? i have Android SDK as shown in screenshot.

```
>cordova build
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\tpt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: C:\Users\tpt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Android Studio do not use the templates, so manually copy and paste template worked:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995556/285594