# How to add templates\gradle\wrapper into android sdk tools?

Tags: cordova

when I tried to build cordova sample project command line shows following error . how to fix this?

```
 C:\Users\Nuwanst\Documents\cordova_dev\cordova\hello>cordova build
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Nuwanst\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
    Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
    Looked here: C:\Users\Nuwanst\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper
```

Comment: Check if it helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43356833/cordova-android-requirements-failed-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gra/44592751#44592751

Comment: I fixed that problem with this instructions.https://stackoverflow.com/a/42995556/8403075