# ionic2: Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

This error has plagued me for a week now.  I installed android studio, sdk and gradle and don't set variables in mac and Everything was working fine and I was running my ionic app in android devices and emulators until I got this error when I run on android:

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make 
sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set 
the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I set the ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables in ~/.bash_profile which I created (the file wasn't exist in the system) but I still have the same error what should I do to solve this problem, 
and when I enter "android" in terminal I got that output:

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.  

For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and 
tools/bin/avdmanager

*********************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command "-version"

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

what should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I also met this problem with my ionic-cli v3.9.2, and I found that the problem is reported by a file which is located in `${YOUR_PROJECT_DIR}/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js`. The `check_android_target` method in this file use `android list targets --compact` command to check if you have installed android env correctly. But the correct command for this check is `android list target --compact` (notice `target` not `targets`) . Maybe it's a typo in old version cordova.

Ionic doesn't integrate the latest release of cordova. So my solution is fix this typo manually and it works.

UPDATE：
When you fix the first problem，maybe you will meet another problem that the ionic-cli will tell you that you don't have a emulator installed but you actually have one. It's another typo in `${YOUR_PROJECT_DIR}platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js`. just change `android list avds` to `android list avd` will make it work.

And then I found there's one more problems which causes the emulator can not be launched. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310182/error-could-not-find-gradle-wrapper-within-android-sdk-might-need-to-update-yo#42995556) will help you.