# Ionic project build error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

`ionic cordova build android`

I got this error

> ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project

I had the ANDROID_HOME environment variable in the correct path.

My cordova version is 6.0.0

My android sdk tools version is 26.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic2: Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID\_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835539/ionic2-error-android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-n)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set ANDROID_HOME enviroment

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk //for linux
```